# CountDown On Every 5 Seconds using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to make like select seconds from dropdown and that second will show countdown like select 5sec, 5sec countdown till then A button is green After 5 sec B will be green same till D will be green.

i have this code for countdown.

```
 var Remaining = $('#Second').val();
        var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById("lbltime").textContent = Remaining;
            Remaining = Remaining - 1;
            if (Remaining <= 0)
                clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        }, 1000);
```

> but it stop only in one countdown not repeat.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzacf.png)

Comment: have you heard of `setInterval` in javascript? If not then google it, you will find your solution

Comment: var Remaining = $('#Second').val();
            var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
                document.getElementById("lbltime").textContent = Remaining;
                Remaining = Remaining - 1;
                if (Remaining <= 0)
                    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            }, 1000);

Comment: i down this . but how to put in loop. @BhushanKawadkar

Comment: your question is very unclear. Please share your code in your question not in comments and make a working code snippet. Also please be more clear

Comment: can you share your html too

Comment: Add the html in pic @BhushanKawadkar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setInterval API.

```
setInterval(function(){
  /* Write your code here that runs for every 5 seconds*/
  },5000)
```

Learn about the setInterval api [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want something like below.

```js
var Remaining = $('#Second').val();
var downloadTimer;

function start(select) {
  clearInterval(downloadTimer);
  $('#Second').val($(select).val());
  Remaining = $('#Second').val();
  document.getElementById("lbltime").textContent = Remaining;
  $('.dv.active').removeClass('active');

  if ($(select).val() == 0)
    return;

  $('.dv:first').addClass('active');

  downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
    Remaining = Remaining - 1;
    if (Remaining <= 0) {
      Remaining = $('#Second').val();
      var current = $('.dv.active').removeClass('active');
      if (current.next('.dv').length)
        current.next('.dv').addClass('active');
      else {
        $('.dv:first').addClass('active');
        // If you want to stop after first iteration then uncomment below line.
        // clearInterval(downloadTimer);
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("lbltime").textContent = Remaining;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.dv {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dv.active {
  background-color: #0F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="Second" val="0" />
<select onchange="start(this)">
  <option value="0"> select</option>
  <option value="3"> 3</option>
  <option value="4"> 4</option>
  <option value="5"> 5</option>
</select>
<div>Time Remaining: <label id="lbltime"></label></div>
<div>
  <div class="dv" id="a"> A</div>
  <div class="dv" id="b"> B</div>
  <div class="dv" id="c"> C</div>
  <div class="dv" id="d"> D</div>
</div>
```